# Can I recover a file that was overwritten when it was omitted from a git commit?

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have been working on a project for a couple of days and had touched about six files in the project.  I was ready to commit.  I'm using Team Explorer on Visual Studio 2019 and the Changes all seemed to be there, so I clicked Commit All and Sync.  Everything went smoothly, no merge conflicts.

The problem occurred when I reviewed my work and realised that one of the javascript files had not been included in the commit, so during the sync process it reverted to the previous commit, which means I've lost about a week's work.

Is there any possibility that this has been cleverly saved somewhere?  And given that it's tracked by git and not included in the git ignore, why was it not committed along with everything else?

I'm almost in despair at this, because it's been a complete nightmare getting this to work at all ... so if anyone can help, I'd be eternally grateful.

PS I've looked at ls -lRt .git/objects and I can see some stuff there which may include the file I need, but how do I get it out?

[image]

Comment: If you never staged _or_ committed this particular file, and then you pulled, overwriting your work, then your only real hope here would be if Visual Studio maintains a local history of all files.  If it does, then you may look through that local history to see if you can find your version somewhere.

Comment: It was last committed eight days ago.  I think I'm just going to have to start again from scratch.  I thought git was reliable - seems it's not a bulletproof as I thought.

Comment: My advice here: _Ditch_ using the VS Git plugin until you have mastered Git from the command line bash tool.  Start using the bash, get fluent using it, and then, if you find it easier or perhaps taking less time, use the VS Git plugin.  What happened to you could never have happened to me if I were using the command line bash.

Comment: As it happens I used bash for about three years previous to my current role, but here everyone uses VS Git and I fell into the habit.  I've now reverted to the One True Path Of Bash.

Comment: Sounds good.  Nothing wrong with Git plugins, I just used one a minute ago (IntelliJ).  Plugins have a place, but for fine grain control, I always recommend the bash.  Don't be _bash_ full about using the Git bash `:-)`